# this.loggedIn is set to true only after a few seconds, how to wait for its value

Tags: angular

In the ts file in am console logging this.loggedIn  and when I enter the correct username and password the access token is stored in the local storage and in the console first false value is printed and then after 2 seconds true gets printed in the console.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

    checkStatus = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    isUserLoggedIn = this.checkStatus.asObservable();

    readonly loginUrl= 'http://********';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    checkLogin() {
        const access_token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
        if(access_token) 
        {
            this.checkStatus.next(true);
        } else {
            this.checkStatus.next(false);
        }
    }

    loginUser(user: any) {
        return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, user)
        .subscribe((success1: any) => {
            if(success1) {
                localStorage.setItem('access_token', success1.success.token);
                // localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(success.success.token));
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**This is my ts:**

```
this.api.loginUser(user);
this.api.isUserLoggedIn.subscribe( (val) => {
    // this.loggedIn = val.valueOf();
    this.loggedIn = val;
    console.log(this.loggedIn);
    this.route.navigate(['/dashboard']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is returning false at first because at that time user is not logged in and `val` is returning false but when the user is logged in new value is emitted and that is true. Try this.

```
loginUser(user: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, user);
  }
```

And when the user is logged in

```
this.api.loginUser(user).subscribe( () => {
     this.api.isUserLoggedIn.subscribe( (val) => {
     localStorage.setItem('access_token', success1.success.token);
     this.loggedIn = val;
     console.log(this.loggedIn);
     this.route.navigate(['/dashboard']);
  });
});
```